# Ambient data logger error exception?

Tags: 2013, dd4t

Can anyone provide any insight as to what is causing this error?  The site in question works for some devs not others.  I don't think it's a license issue, but even if it was, wouldn't the license issue come later?   This appears to occur before the license check. Since it seems to be blowing up on the logger, there are no log files.

Edit:  I copied the code,jars & configs from a working server so all of that should be in place.  Sounds like a permissions issue, but what?  I checked everything.

```
<JavaException>
 <Type>java/lang/ClassNotFoundException</Type>
 <Message><![CDATA[org.slf4j.LoggerFactory]]></Message>
 <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory at com.codemesh.classloader.ExtensibleClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at com.codemesh.classloader.ExtensibleClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at com.codemesh.classloader.ExtensibleClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at com.codemesh.bootstrap.JarInputStreamBootstrapper.forName(Unknown Source)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init()
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject()
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
  at Org.Slf4j.LoggerFactory.GetLogger(String name)
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Utilities.LoggerFactory.GetLogger(String loggerName)
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule..cctor()]]></StackTrace>
</JavaException>
```

Comment: if your system 64 bit, you should copy the jars and dll meant for that only, and make sure Enable 32 bit application set to false in application pool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i will suggest following:

- if your system 64 bit, you should copy the jars and dll meant for that only, and make sure **Enable 32 bit application** set to false in application pool.
- if your system is 32 bit, make sure all dll and jars are of 32 bit only.
- Make Sure cd_ambient.jar and Slf4j related Jars are present in the bin\lib
- Validate License , check machine name, no of cores in license and should match with system
- Check to be sure you are using the correct Tridion DLL's

Comment: I finally got this working. The problem was with the Tridion DLL's.  The site was linking to more than it needed.  So I deleted the unused ones & copied the ones it was working from another site that did work.  Problem solved.  I listed the comment under this answer since it already had a list of solutions.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Raj has mentioned, it does makes sense that you scanned  your ADF related config file and check for any entry that is unusual (does not exists, unintentional etc.).